# Android studio keeps crashing on launch

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I installed the latest version of android studio. I was able to create and run projects just a few hours ago but now, when I try to open an existing project or trying to create a new one, it crashes (studio exits automatically). The crashing happens mainly two times, when I click the android studio icon to launch it and it starts loading, or when it (somehow) survives the initial loading and the project "starts indexing". I have a strong doubt on intelliJ platform that the studio uses because when I installed the IntelliJ idea IDE separately, the same thing happens. I am desperately looking for a solution. It should be noted that there is no memory issue. I am using Windows 7 ultimate (64-bit).

After each crash a folder is generated in the log folder named `freeze-20161115-145630-5` and it has a file named `threadDump-20161115-145630.txt` and the idea.log file has the following (it is a very long log file. I have deleted some text from the top of the file):

```
2016-11-15 14:56:11,526 [      0]   INFO -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - ------------------------------------------------------ IDE STARTED ------------------------------------------------------ 


    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:217)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:768)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:752)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$8.run(CoreProgressManager.java:357)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$13$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:633)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ebc10f8, pid=4148, tid=0x0000000000000ea4
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_76-b03) (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x3f10f8]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\hs_err_pid4148.log
#
# Compiler replay data is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\replay_pid4148.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:153)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:136)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:111)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:89)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:150)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:135)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:202)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:116)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    ... 3 more
2016-11-15 14:56:33,144 [  21618]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at 'C:\Users\DJ\AndroidStudioProjects\App' 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.14.1'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:217)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:768)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:752)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$8.run(CoreProgressManager.java:357)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$13$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:633)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ebc10f8, pid=4148, tid=0x0000000000000ea4
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_76-b03) (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x3f10f8]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\hs_err_pid4148.log
#
# Compiler replay data is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\replay_pid4148.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:153)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:136)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:111)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:89)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:150)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:135)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:202)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:116)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    ... 3 more
2016-11-15 14:56:33,159 [  21633]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ebc10f8, pid=4148, tid=0x0000000000000ea4
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_76-b03) (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x3f10f8]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\hs_err_pid4148.log
#
# Compiler replay data is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\replay_pid4148.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ebc10f8, pid=4148, tid=0x0000000000000ea4
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_76-b03) (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x3f10f8]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\hs_err_pid4148.log
#
# Compiler replay data is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\replay_pid4148.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:579)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:405)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:772)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:752)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$1.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$8.run(CoreProgressManager.java:357)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$13$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:633)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-11-15 14:56:33,159 [  21633]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2016-11-15 14:56:33,159 [  21633]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ebc10f8, pid=4148, tid=0x0000000000000ea4
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_76-b03) (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x3f10f8]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\hs_err_pid4148.log
#
# Compiler replay data is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\replay_pid4148.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#


Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-11-15 14:56:33,159 [  21633]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'App' failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ebc10f8, pid=4148, tid=0x0000000000000ea4
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_76-b03) (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x3f10f8]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\hs_err_pid4148.log
#
# Compiler replay data is saved as:
# C:\Users\DJ\.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\replay_pid4148.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#


Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-11-15 14:56:34,205 [  22679]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - C:/Users/DJ/AndroidStudioProjects/App/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2016-11-15 14:56:34,267 [  22741]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 140ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2016-11-15 14:56:35,016 [  23490]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 5625 ms
```

Comment: Anything in the Event Viewer logs?

Comment: Goto SDK Manager and update all available items to latest version.

Comment: I am a newbie and don't know where to access logs

Comment: C:\Users\USERNAME\.AndroidStudioX.X\system\log - path of studio log file

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting your .gradle from C:\Users\ directory and try again.

if not,

Run Android Studio "as administrator"

if not,

Completely uninstall Android Studio and Reinstall the latest version.

Or

Update and configure java.

Comment: running as administrator doesn't help

Comment: What is your windows version ?

Comment: Try deleting your .gradle from C:\Users\ directory and try again.

Comment: I also have similar problem on my Windows 10 machine. I have tried to re-install windows, it didn't help.

I have uninstalled 64-bit java and installed 32-bit java, but still didn't help. 
For now, I am using Linux virtualization to work on android, which is ridiculously slow. 

Unfortunately, I could not find any solution after googling a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I tried reinstalling Android Studio and the problem persisted. Second time round I did a more complete uninstall using an uninstaller. But I noticed that my uninstaller was not entierly removing the C:\Program Files\Android folder. I tried to delete this in Windows Explorer and it told me "The action can't be completed because the file is open in another program". So I downloaded Process Explorer, used ctrl+f and searched android. I then killed all the processes that were opening the file (java.exe and abd.exe) and then deleted the folder. When I reinstalled Android Studio it worked again!

It's slightly unsatifying because I never located the source of the issue and I'm not entierly sure whether using a dedicated uninstaller or deleting the C:\Program Files\Android folder is the source of my fix. But I'm just happy to have it working again.

Comment: Hi There. Try to articulate your answer using bullets and bold text to bring focus to the main parts. This would help increase the answer's reaach.